# How to set session attributes in Spring Boot?

Tags: java, spring-boot, session, httpsession

I want to set a *session attribute* with the name that is send by user. User will first login in. And when he logged in I want that his username will set as session attribute.

What should I do?

This is my controller:

```
@GetMapping("/login")
public String login() {
    return "Login";
}

@PostMapping("/loginCheck")
public String checkLogin(@ModelAttribute("users") Users user) {
    if (userService.checkUser(user)) {
        return "redirect:/"+user.getUsername()+"/";
    } else {
        return "Login";
    }
}

@PostMapping("/signup")
public ModelAndView createuser(@ModelAttribute("users") Users user) {
    if (userService.checkUser(user)) {
        return new ModelAndView("Login");
    } else {
        userService.adduser(user);
        return new ModelAndView("Login");
    }
}
```

Now how I set the username as session which I am getting in `user.getUsername()`?

Answer (score 6):

In SpringMVC you can have the HttpSession injected automatically by adding it as a parameter to your method. So, you login could be something similar to:

```
@GetMapping("/login")
public String login(@ModelAttribute("users") Users user, HttpSession session)
{
    if(userService.authUser(user)) { //Made this method up
        session.setAttribute("username", user.getUsername());
        view.setViewName("homepage"); //Made up view
    }
    else{
        return new ModelAndView("Login");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use Spring Security, registered a bean listening for Spring Security's `InteractiveAuthenticationSuccessEvent` and `SessionDestroyedEvent` events. These events fire without any explicit configuration in a default Spring Boot environment.

See https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#web.security:

> The basic features you get by default in a web application are:
>
> - . . .
> - A DefaultAuthenticationEventPublisher for publishing authentication events.

By handling these events you can add "username" as a session attribute immediately after a user logons and remove that attribute when the security session (security context) is destroyed:

```
@Component
public class SessionStoreUsernameAuthEventHandler {

  @EventListener
  public void audit(InteractiveAuthenticationSuccessEvent e) {
    getSession().ifPresent(s -> s.setAttribute("username", e.getAuthentication().getName()));
  }

  @EventListener
  public void audit(SessionDestroyedEvent e) {
    getSession().ifPresent(s -> s.removeAttribute("username"));
  }
  
  private static Optional<HttpServletRequest> getCurrentRequest() {
    return Optional.ofNullable(RequestContextHolder.getRequestAttributes())
      .filter(ServletRequestAttributes.class::isInstance)
      .map(ServletRequestAttributes.class::cast)
      .map(ServletRequestAttributes::getRequest);
  }

  private static Optional<HttpSession> getSession() {
    return getCurrentRequest().map(HttpServletRequest::getSession);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@Autowired
ObjectFactory<HttpSession> httpSessionFactory;
.
.
.
HttpSession session = httpSessionFactory.getObject();
```

[Works good. Thanks to this post.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48489304/1690081)